# To regularize every incidence of the term 'Heb' to "HEB" in pandas df

Tags: data-cleaning, regex-group

In a pandas df, trying to regularize every incidence of the term 'Heb' to "HEB"

In a pandas df, trying to regularize every incidence of the term 'Heb' to "HEB"
using sidetable, I tried this and it worked.
`(df['Description'].str.contains('H-E-B', case=False, regex=False), 'HEB'),`
but then I tried this and it didn't work.
`(df['Description'].str.contains(['HEB', 'H-E-B', 'Heb online' ], case=False, regex=False), 'HEB'),`

Error message reads:"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'upper'"

Would expect
Input:

| Description | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| HEB | 100.00 |
| HEB#123 | 100.00 |
| HEB online | 100.00 |
| H-E-B Gas | 100.00 |
| Heb Carwash | 100.00 |

Output:

| Description | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| HEB | 100.00 |
| HEB | 100.00 |
| HEB | 100.00 |
| HEB | 100.00 |
| HEB | 100.00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str.contains()` method expects a string and you are giving it a list of strings instead, that's why you are getting the AttributeError.

To replace all descriptions that contain some variation of `'Heb'` with `'HEB'` you can create a list that contains all expected variations, then loop over the rows of your dataframe and compare the description with your variations:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'Description': ['HEB', 'HEB#123', 'HEB online', 'H-E-B Gas', 'Heb Carwash'],
        'Amount': [100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
patterns = ['HEB', 'H-E-B', 'Heb' ]


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern in df.at[index, 'Description']:
            df.at[index, 'Description'] = 'HEB'

print(df)
```